# chrome packaged app reload html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How can I reload complete html of a chrome packaged app. I do not want to do `chrome.runtime.reload()`. Is there something which can be done using `chrome.app.window.current()`?

Comment: We'll see what others say, but I believe the answer is, "You can't."

Comment: Your question is confusing because you say "reload complete HTML" as if that were more powerful than chrome.runtime.reload(). Are you actually asking how to reload just one window of a Chrome App?

Comment: @sowbug yeah just one window of the app.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking about how to reload just one app window, try calling `close()` on the  appropriate `AppWindow`, then have your event page create it again.

If you're asking how to replace the DOM in an app window, then replace the DOM, just as you would in any other single-page webapp.